# django-haystack 2.0.0beta facet example - not showing facet counts

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I've been working through the documentation for Haystack 2.0.0beta, and using solr3.6.0 as my backend.  I have gotten through the getting started example.  Working with the facet example now.

search_indexes.py

```
import datetime
from haystack import indexes
from bsmain.models import Note

class NoteIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    author = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user', faceted=True)
    pub_date = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='pub_date')

def get_model(self):
    return Note

def index_queryset(self):
    """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
    return self.get_model().objects.filter(pub_date__lte=datetime.datetime.now())
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import FacetedSearchView
sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('author')

urlpatterns = patterns('haystack.views',
    url(r'^$', FacetedSearchView(form_class=FacetedSearchForm,searchqueryset=sqs),
        name='haystack_search'),
)
```

I have tested in python shell and get facets and counts, but when I fire the /search url (with the html provided in the example for facets) I get the form but no facets or counts.
Can anyone see anything wrong in the code above or is there somehing else I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your html, I assume there must be some typo there...

Answer (score 0):

Did you rebuild the index (`./manage.py rebuild_index`)?

Once done then create the schema.xml (`./manage.py build_solr_scema > schema.xml`)

Then copy the shcema.xml to your solr conf directory and restart the solr.

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I believe if he already got facet counts from shell it's pointless to rebuild index, as facets are there...